# Problems with % percent sign in fancyvrb inline \Verb

Tags: syntax, comments, fancyvrb, word-count

I have some programming language code examples in a fancyvrb `\Verb!...!` expression. This includes the modulus operator which happens to be a percent sign, e.g.

```
\Verb!(1..100) select: { arg i; i % 7 == 0 }!
```

This causes two problems. First, TeXShop thinks there is a line comment beginning after the `%` (just as this stackexchange display gets it wrong). This is a purely aesthetic problem.

But more severely, while the document gets properly set with LaTeX, the `texcount` and `texcountfull` programmes jump off the rails, and produce an error which makes the word count stop at that point till the end of the `.tex` file:

```
!!! Warning: END group without type while waiting to end tabular. !!!

!!! Warning: END group without type while waiting to end sidewaystable. !!!
```

(The `\Verb` appears within a table within a rotate figure).

I guess I must find some workaround by escaping the `%` characters. But how?

Comment: you are doing something different. Using a minimal example with only loading `fancyvrb` will not create such warning. So create a complete example which shows your behaviour! And is there any reason why you do not use `\verb` (lowercase v)

Comment: @Herbert the warning is emitted by the `texcount` macro. As I said, the text is set correctly, but the wordcount chokes. I'll try to create a full document to post here. I am using fancyvrb all over, because of easier font customisation, I don't want to switch to `\verb`.

Comment: I don't think `texcount` is aware of `\Verb`; it knows `\verb` and `verbatim`. I don't know if one can extend it to treat also `\Verb`.

Comment: what is `texcount`? A package?

Comment: It's a [utility](http://app.uio.no/ifi/texcount/index.html) to generate a word count of latex files (words in main text, headers, footnotes, etc., per chapter). It's a standard CTAN package I think.

Comment: Does your programming language use any ``\`` as part of the code?

Comment: @JLDiaz no, that could be used for escaping. But how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this is probably a simple patch to `texcount.pl`.  Search the script for `\verb` to find this block:

```
  } elsif ($next eq '\verb') {
    _parse_verb_region($tex,$status);
```

Then simply add a copy of this block with `\Verb` instead of `\verb`:

```
  } elsif ($next eq '\Verb') {
    _parse_verb_region($tex,$status);
```

This should get rid of the errors.

It seems that `texcount` doesn't know about `sidewaystable`, so the count of floats may be off unless you figure out how to add it.

Comment: @Emit_Taste Also, based on this answer, could you simply add `\let\verb=\Verb` in your preamble, and then use `\verb` instead of `\Verb` in the rest of your document? If this works, that would avoid the patch to `texcount.pl`.

Comment: Thanks, I will take this as an answer if nothing else shows up. @JLDiaz - unfortunately the alias doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I could get as far as this:

```
\newcommand{\escapepercent}{\%}

\Verb[commandchars=\\<>]!(1..100) select: { arg i; i \escapepercent 7 == 0 }!
```

This makes everything in the system happy. The only two things I don't like is (a) there is always a space character after the inserted percent. This is fine for the examples I have right now, but I would like to control this explicitly. (b) I can't get to use other grouping characters with `commandchars`, which is nasty because `<` and `>` may also appear in the source. For example, `\Verb[commandchars=\\äö]` would always print the group closing character (in this case `ö`) for some reason...

Finally if I could define an alias for the above `\Verb` so that I don't have to type the `commandchars` in every occurrence, that would help.

If you help me on these ones, I'm happy to check your answer :)

Comment: Spaces in `\Verb` are not normal spaces, so they aren't ignored at the end of control sequences. If you use UTF-8, `ä` is *two* tokens, as far as TeX is concerned, which become the delimiters. The following `ö` is then printed, because it remains in the input stream. However, if you use `commandchars`, I guess that `\%` will work without the need for `\escapepercent`.

Comment: Ok. The problem is that basically all 7-bit ASCII characters occur in the language that I'm using, so I was hoping for some other characters. I use `[utf8]{inputenc}`, but that doesn't seem to help. I'm getting away now mostly with `commandchars=\\!!` although I might need to switch occasionally when the bang `!` is used in the source. All a bit hackish...

Comment: @EmitTaste Remove `inputenc` package and try to compile with `lualatex` or `xelatex`, which have native utf8 support.

Comment: @JLDiaz this is not possible anymore. I have a 40K word text body, I already had a hard time when I updated the TeX version at some point during my work. I don't want to touch the packages any more if possible. Anyway, thanks for your comments!

Comment: @EmitTaste You can give it a try anyway and compile with `lualatex`. Perhaps the only change required is to remove `inputenc`.

Comment: As egreg said, if you define ``\`` as command character, it is enough to write `\%`.

Comment: @Speravir No, I tried it and it does not work, presumably because `Verb` redefines the category code of `%`

Comment: @JLDiaz It must be another reason then, because I used it frequently and made a new test now: It works fine here with `\Verb[commandchars=\\<>]|% \%|` and also with `\begin{Verbatim}[commandchars=\\<>]` etc.

Answer (score 2):

For typesetting program fragments, look at the listings package. It knows of many languages, and does a good job at typesetting program fragments and even complete source files.

Comment: `listings` also works together with `fancyvrb`, not in all details, though.

Answer (score 0):

Normally to escape a sign in LaTeX, you use `\`. So `\%`, not sure if this will work here, but it can't hurt to try. :)

Comment: Yes, I tried that. `texcount` then works, but fancyvrb prints also the backslash which it shouldn't of course.

Comment: This would obviously be a hack, but could you add a line break after % without changing the layout?

Comment: No :-( This gives "Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetVerb."